# Bootstrap Popover in an LI

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Im attempting to do a pop over with bootstrap and keep the existing div formatting.

How can i fix the code below to make it work.

```
 <ul class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: courses">
  <li class="list-group-item CourseHover" data-bind="css: { hidden : isSatisfied}" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
    <a tabindex="0" class="" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
          <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-10">
                   <span data-bind="text:courseName"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2">
                   <span data-bind="text:courseCredits"></span> cr
               </div>
          </div>
    </a>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popovers have to be [initialized by jquery](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers).

This code should do the trick:

```
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

You also might want to put data-placement="bottom" or data-placement="top" in your anchor tag -- the popover otherwise might appear way to the right.